# Webpage inside WKWebview not responds to touch event

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Code:

```
override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView?.uiDelegate = self as! WKUIDelegate
        view = webView

    }

override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL (string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView?.load(request)
    }
```

I am loading a webpage using WKWebView.It successfully load the web page.I am unable interact with webpage(i.e.tapping button or link).what is wrong with my code.any help will be appricated.thanks in advance

Comment: try to set the WKWebViewDelegate to self at viewDidLoad() or viewWillApplear() method.

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Comment: @vinay you tested in device or simulator?

Comment: which simulator?

Comment: tested in on simulator iPhone 5s and It works well on device too.